# Uniform probability distribution ( continuous)

Tags: probability, continuity, uniform-distribution, density-function, descriptive-statistics

In a psychological study involving personality types and career selections, it is found that the time
required to complete the task is uniformly distributed over the interval from 5.0 minutes to 7.5
minutes. What is the:
i) mean and standard deviation of the time interval?
ii) probability that the task is completed in 7.0 or more minutes?
iii) probability that the task is completed between 5.5 to 6.5 minutes?
iv) probability that it requires more than 9.0 minutes to complete?
I HAVE SUCCESSFULLY ANSWERED FROM (i)->(iii) but I am stuck at (iv).How do I solve the question if the value is more than the upper boundary of x (7.5 mins)?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. There is no need to repeat questions that you have already answered on your own.

Comment: All of the probability is in the interval $(5.0,  7.5),$ so none of the probability is beyond 9.